# Joomla 2.5 component geting data from database on admin

Tags: php, database, components, joomla2.5, admin

I want to get data from database in admin section of my component.
The strange thing is that the same code works on site part of my component but does not work on the admin part.

models/statistic_adm.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.application.component.model');
jimport( 'joomla.database.database' );
jimport( 'joomla.database.table' );

class sblogModelstatistic_adm extends JModel
{
    public function getCode(){
        $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = 'SELECT `code` FROM `#__sblog_ustawienia`';
        $db->setQuery($query);
        return $db->loadRowList();
    }
}
```

views/statistic_adm/tmpl/default.php

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die('Restricted Access');
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
jimport( 'joomla.filter.output' );

$tabela = $this->get('getCode');
$code = $tabela[0][0];
?>

<form action="index.php?option=com_sblog&view=statistic_adm" method="post" name="adminForm">

<label>Kod bloga:</label> <input type='text' name='code' value="<?php echo $tabela[0][0]; ?>" />

<input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />

</form>
```

views/statistic_adm/tmpl/view.html.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
jimport('joomla.application.component.view');

class sblogViewStatistic_adm extends JView
{
    function display($tpl = null)
    {
        JSubMenuHelper::addEntry(JText::_('Ustawienia'), 'index.php?option=com_sblog&amp;view=statistic_adm', true);
        JToolBarHelper::title( JText::_('System blogowy'), 'generic.png' );

        $task   = JRequest::getCmd('task');    
        $model = &$this->getModel('statistic_adm');

        //$model=JFactory::getDBO();
        $getCode = $model->getCode();
        $this->assignRef('getCode', $getCode);

        $this->addToolBar();
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
     protected function addToolBar() {          
        if (JRequest::getVar('layout') != 'edit')  
        {  
            JToolBarHelper::save('save','Zapisz');
        }
    }  
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What happens when it `doesn't work`? An error message? Just a blank page?

Comment: Just dont display the variable from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are directly call your model function `getcode` into your template without defining the model. Also you already assign the value of `getcode` function in `view.html.php` ,so you can directly call that variable into your template like below,

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die('Restricted Access');
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
jimport( 'joomla.filter.output' );

//get the value assigned in the view.html.php
$tabela = $this->getCode;
$code = $tabela[0][0];
?>

<form action="index.php?option=com_sblog&view=statistic_adm" method="post" name="adminForm">   
<label>Kod bloga:</label> <input type='text' name='code' value="<?php echo $code; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
</form>
```

Hope this will help you.